# What is the "Adjustment" preference in WatchKit-Storyboard for?

Tags: ios, watchkit

I couldn't really find anything on the web yet, what the **Adjustment** preference on WatchKit's UI elements does.

[image: XCode - InterfaceBuilder Screenshot]

**Does somebody know?**

Comment: What does it say in the docs? What type of element are you currently selecting here? What class?

Comment: I couldn't find any docs on that. So seems to be wired private API. E.g. when selecting a ``WKInterfaceLabel`` which inherits from ``WKInterfaceObject``. Neither of them have an "adjustment" property or related methods.

Comment: Hmm... That's odd. Normally each bit of interface builder is just a replacement for code. Very odd.

Comment: Remembering that all Apple Watch interfaces must be built in interface builder, and can't be created in code, there are going to be elements that can't be altered in code. That said, quite possible this will be available and just hasn't been implemented yet. Could be an enhancement request to file if wanted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The adjustment will add or subtract that many points from the size of the element.  Say you have an element who's height is set relative to the container at 50% and then you add an adjustment of 10.  If the containers height is 100 then that element's height will be 60 since it will be 50% of 100 plus 10.  I am using it in my app to get the exact height that I want relative to the height of the watch.